# Need to store data in Queue should be permanent until delete

Tags: java, queue

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Queue {
    public static java.util.Queue<String> que = new LinkedList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println(que);

        que.add("a");
        que.add("b");
        que.add("c");
        que.add("d");

        System.out.println(que);

    }

}
```

In the above code , the values are stored temporarily , when i run 1st , 2nd , 3rd  time ,... the output will be same as below :

```
[]
[a, b, c, d]
```

I need the queue data should store permanently 
when i run 2nd time , the o/p should be

```
[a, b, c, d]
[a, b, c, d,a, b, c, d]
```

.......

How this can be done ? Please help me ?
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Are you wanting to have a [persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) mechanism? This seems to be an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for some persistence. Depending on what the application is doing, why don't you use a simple text file to read/write the contents of the queue whenever the program starts/exits?

Alternatively, you can use a database if your are doing something a little more serious.

Comment: In my application, i am going to track user information during loading  my app to client site .. If i store the information to db in runtime , then my app will load slow.. To avoid that i am going to insert datas to Queue and in background process i will store the queue data to db and delete queue.. And the data will be more when more users uses my app, so is it right way to store the queue data to file ?

Comment: I think using a file would be the best way for this; the only cost your program will bare would be that of reading from and writing to the file. And this, in any case, will happen when the program starts and when it exits so it would almost be oblivious to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can save / read queue to a file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("queue");
    if (file.exists()) {
        try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            que = (java.util.Queue<String>)is.readObject();
        }
    } else {
        que = new LinkedList<String>();
    }
    System.out.println(que);
    que.add("a");
    que.add("b");
    que.add("c");
    que.add("d");
    System.out.println(que);
    try (ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
        os.writeObject(que);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. If writing data to file takes few time than storing data to db?

Comment: I think writing to a local file is supposed to be faster than writing to a remote DB

Comment: File and DB will be in the same server .. Which one is faster ? Otherwise any alternative solution is there?

Comment: I dont think there will be significant difference, there is another thing to consider - saving to file with Serilization is much simpler